# How to pass props to a dynamically selected component using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a Section.tsx component which determines which component it should render based on the "bundle" value in the props, which is fetched from our CMS. The component works fine, but I'm trying to find a type-safe way to pass the "section" prop to the selected component. I'm assuming generics is the way to solve this, but being quite new to typescript I'm having a hard time visualising how it can work.

How can I pass props to the generated component?

Section.tsx:

```
import Banner1 from './content/Banner1/Banner1';

const sectionMap = {
  banner_1: Banner1,
};

type SectionProps = {
  section: {
    bundle: string;
    paragraph: Object;
  };
};

export default function Section({ section }: SectionProps) {
  const name = section.bundle as keyof typeof sectionMap;

  const SectionComponent = sectionMap[name as keyof typeof sectionMap]
    ? sectionMap[name as keyof typeof sectionMap]
    : null;

  // @ts-ignore -- HOW DO SOLVE THIS?
  return SectionComponent && <SectionComponent section={section} />;
}
```

Banner1.tsx:

```
import ImageType from '@/types/Image.type';
import Heading from '@/components/atoms/typography/heading/Heading';
import ImageCrop from '@/components/atoms/image/ImageCrop';

export type Banner1Props = {
  section: {
    bundle: string;
    paragraph: {
      field_title: string;
      field_description: string;
      field_image: ImageType;
    };
  };
};

const Banner1 = ({ section: { paragraph: data } }: Banner1Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ImageCrop src={data.field_image.url} alt={data.field_image.alt} />
      <Heading as={'h1'} size={'small'}>
        {data.field_title}
      </Heading>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.field_description }}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Banner1;
```

The typescript error:

```
Type '{ bundle: string; paragraph: Object; }' is not assignable to type '{ bundle: string; paragraph: { field_title: string; field_description: string; field_image: ImageType; }; }'.
  Types of property 'paragraph' are incompatible.
    The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
      Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type '{ field_title: string; field_description: string; field_image: ImageType; }': field_title, field_description, field_image
```

Comment: maybe try using `object` instead of `Object`. You could also use this create only one type for both cases and use `|` in the paragraph prop to tell typescript it can be any of those